# Simulation of dust from landing on the moon

Tags: animation, particles, fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I'm doing a moon landing animation and I need to simulate dust. The lunar module lands and as it approaches the surface, the rocket engine blows dust in all directions. The lunar module lands and the dust settles. Something like in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lbvesj72CWU

Or at least this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqEBAcoz6gE

I got some results with quicksmoke, but it's not quite there. I especially couldn't get the dust to settle and the whole thing looks weird. Any ideas how to do this?

[image]

Comment: maybe wanna ask NASA how they did it? :D

Comment: I doubt anyone there can still remember! :^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking *particles* rather than smoke.  Here's my attempt:

[image]

I set up a fluid simulation (quick fluid) on a cube that I set to Inflow and animated "use flow" for some 40 frames, with initial upwards velocity to counter gravity:

[image]

In the domain object, for the particle system, I chose a simple ico-sphere as the rendering object (pebble).

[image]

and in the Fluid Domain I did *not* add liquid mesh (keep as particles), added sluggishness with viscosity and diffusion, and animated gravity from low to high values after the particle inflow up-shooting stops.

[image].

I added a plane as a Collision surface for the particles, heavy on stickiness  and damping:

[image]

And I gift my example [image]

... and ignore Chris and John_E: they must be high on spring pollen today!  And I would use the same solution for Elon Musk landing on Mars, except for the color scheme.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it definitely pointed me in the right direction. Finally, I used smoke as fine dust and particles as small stones. I blow it all off with force.